# Is the projection function convex?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Define the following function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ to be the projection function onto a convex and a closed set C

$f(x)=\arg\min_{y\in C} ||x-y||_2^2 $

Denote $f_i(x)$  $i=1,...,n$ the components of $f$.

Is it true to claim that the $f_i(x)$ $i=1,...,n$ are convex functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

For example take n=1, C = [0,1].

Then  f(x) = 0 if x<0; f(x) = x for x in [0,1] and f(x) = 1 for x>1. And this function is not convex.

Answer (score 3):

No, the $f_i$'s are not convex in general. A counter-example in any dimension $n$ is the projection onto the $\ell_2$ unit ball $C := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | \|x\| \le 1\}$. Indeed, for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ one computes
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) := proj_C(x) = \begin{cases}x, &\mbox{ if }\|x\| \le 1,\\\frac{1}{\|x\|}x, &\mbox{ otherwise.}\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}
Here, the component functions $f_i$ are given by
\begin{eqnarray}
f_i(x) = \begin{cases}x_i, &\mbox{ if }\|x\| \le 1,\\\frac{1}{\|x\|}x_i, &\mbox{ otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}
It's clear that **none** of the $f_i$ is convex.

However, if you're not interested in the point at which the minimum (in your the general projection problem) is attained (**argmin**) but, the value minimum value itself (**min**), then this defines convex function. Indeed, the function
\begin{eqnarray}
x \mapsto \underset{y \in C}{\text{min }}\frac{1}{2}\|y-x\|^2 = \underset{y \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{min }}\frac{1}{2}\|y-x\|^2 + i_C(y)
\end{eqnarray}
corresponds to the *Mureau envelope* of the indicator function $i_C: y \mapsto \begin{cases}0, &\mbox{ if}y \in C,\\+\infty, &\mbox{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$

**An example where all the $f_i$'s are convex**

Let $C = \mathbb{R}^n_+ := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | x_i \ge 0\text{ } \forall i\}$, the nonnegative $n$th orthant. Then $f_i(x) = max(0, x_i)$ defines a convex function for each $i$.

Hope this helps :)